# Generalization of parallelogram law

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was asked to find a corresponding result for finite set $\{z_1, \cdots, z_n\}$ complex numbers like parallelogram law using induction. But I have no idea about that, how could it be a parallelogram if one more point is added with two points? I searched online I am getting results only for higher dimensional. Please help me anyone.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): **Avoid "no clue" questions.** Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. Such questions will most of the time be rejected by the community...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible generalization would be the following:

Two complex numbers:
$$|a+b|^2+|a-b|^2=2|a|^2+2|b|^2$$

Three complex numbers:
$$|a+b+c|^2+|a+b-c|^2+|a-b+c|^2+|a-b-c|^2=4|a|^2+4|b|^2+4|c|^2$$

Four complex numbers:
$$|a+b+c+d|^2+|a+b+c-d|^2\\
+|a+b-c+d|^2+|a+b-c-d|^2\\
+|a-b+c+d|^2+|a-b+c-d|^2\\
+|a-b-c+d|^2+|a-b-c-d|^2\\
=8|a|^2+8|b|^2+8|c|^2+8|d|^2$$

In gereral $$\sum |z_1 \pm z_2 \pm z_3 \pm \cdots \pm z_n|^2 = 2^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n|z_k|^2$$
where the sum on the LHS is taken over all the possible choices of the signs.

This can be easily proved by induction.